# Hibernate InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException with Custom Type

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm currently converting old java EE project to springboot .I'm encountering an issue with Hibernate when trying to use a custom type (AbsDate)as a primary key in my NurseSchedule entity (this table has two columns as primary key).I have a custom converter (AbsDateConverter) for this type (Which is working perfectly . i have used it in another entities.)

when used this i got

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

but if i change AbsDate to util Date this is working . How to resolve this

here is my entity class

```
@Entity(name="nurseSchedule")
@IdClass(NurseScheduleId.class)
public class NurseSchedule implements java.io.Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userNo")
    public int userNo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "startDate")
    @Convert(converter = AbsDateConverter.class)
    private AbsDate startDate;

    @Column(name = "period")
    @Convert(converter = AbsDateConverter.class)
    public AbsDate period;

    @Column(name = "nDays")
    public Integer nDays;

    @Column(name = "lastModified")
    @Convert(converter = AbsTimeConverter.class)
    public AbsTime lastModified;

    @Column(name = "unitNo")
    public int unitNo;

}
```

this is my id class

```
public class NurseScheduleId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int userNo;
  
    @Convert(converter = AbsDateConverter.class)
    private AbsDate startDate;


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      NurseScheduleId that = (NurseScheduleId) o;

      if (userNo != that.userNo) return false;
      return Objects.equals(startDate, that.startDate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userNo, startDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a stack trace for that error then [edit] your question and post the entire stack trace.